# Appending to every regex match found in string [Python]

Tags: python, regex

Meet string 's':

> AA Well, This is amazing. AA It is. BB Wow. AA As I said.

Here's the code:

```
s = AA Well, This is amazing. AA It is. BB Wow. AA As I said.
separate_words_tuple = s.split()
i = 0
for word in separate_words_tuple:
    check_word = word
    if re.search("[A-Z]+", str(check_word)):
        match = re.search("[A-Z]+", str(check_word))
        if (len(match.group(0)) != 1):
            actor_name = match.group(0) + "_" + str(i)
            print(re.sub(r"[A-Z]+", actor_name, s))
            i += 1
```

Here's what 's' looks like with that code:

> AA_3 AA_3ell, AA_3his is amazing. AA_3 AA_3t is. AA_3 AA_3ow. AA_3
>   AA_3s AA_3 said.

Here's what I want 's' to look like:

> AA_0 Well, This is amazing. AA_1 It is. BB_2 Wow. AA_3 As I said.

Comment: where's the rest of the code?, with `seperate_words_tuple` and `file_string`

Comment: You want to append `_` + counter to any ALLCAPS word?

Comment: @Keatinge updated.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes. Any ALLCAPS word with length more than 1 to be specific.

Comment: Maybe [this will do](http://ideone.com/3VCcWG).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Yes, it does. Thank you so much. 
Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it correct? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *function's static property* to count all matched items. `incCaps()` is a *replacement* callback.

```
s = 'AA Well, This is amazing. AA It is. BB Wow. AA As I said.'

def incCaps(m):
    replaced = m.group(0) + '_' + str(incCaps.counter)
    incCaps.counter += 1
    return replaced

incCaps.counter = 0
s = re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', incCaps, s)

print(s)
```

The output:

```
AA_0 Well, This is amazing. AA_1 It is. BB_2 Wow. AA_3 As I said.
```

Answer (score 0):

@RomanPerekhrest is right - `re.sub` provides us with a great opportunity to pass a function as an argument. But having a global function with a state is a code smell - this function isn't testable or even reusable.

I would suggest two similar ways of refactoring:

1. Having `match_counter` global for reuse:

   ```
   def match_counter():
       counter = -1
       def inc_caps(m):
           counter += 1
           return '{}_{}'.format(m.group(0), counter)
       return inc_caps

   s = re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]{2,}\b', match_counter(), s)
   ```
2. or making the whole thing a single unit of functionality:

   ```
   def replaced_by_counts(regex, string):
       counter = -1
       def inc_caps(m):
           counter += 1
           return '{}_{}'.format(m.group(0), counter)
       return regex.sub(inc_caps, string)
   ```